In auth0, I have trouble with the ASP.NET MVC 5 LogonProceed method call continuously after authentication when it redirect to controller
All configurations are correct, but when I enter credentials, there is no error, but when it redirects to the controller, the LogonProceed method is called continuously. Callback method not called. Auth0 credential popup opens successfully, there is no issue.
